# Do statues block liquids?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Do statues block the flow of liquids?

(Or, the real question: Can I use statues as walls in my magma pump stack?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was pumping a bunch of magma into an underground ocean anyway (in an attempt to destroy an *enormous* amount of forgotten beast contamination), so I tossed a statue into an overflow area.  Did not impede the magma flow in the least.

So no, statues do not block the flow of liquids.

Comment: But they do look good.

Comment: Did you toss it or did you build it? Because no unbuilt object can obstruct anything.

Answer (score 6):

The proper dwarfy answer here would be "gosh, I don't know! Let's try it!" in the hopes that you'd believe me and get magma all over your fort. But in the interest of actually helping you out here, I'll give you this one for free: I'm pretty sure that they do not. Built statues only block creature movement, not liquids; unbuilt statues don't block movement either, and remember that anything with BUILDINGDESTROYER (either 1 or 2) can knock statues over. So don't go thinking that a wall of statues will keep forgotten beasts out, either, because it won't (I tried this once, it didn't go well). Use real walls instead. Yes, they take longer to build, and they aren't worth as much, but unlike statues they actually get the job done.

Comment: Were this any other game I would approve of your not tricking him into a magma flood, but this is Dorf Fortress, and Losing is Fun.